# C++: Checking if an object is empty in a conditional statement

Tags: c++

How would you check to see if an object is empty, and if it is, run a block of code?

The function prototype looks like this:

```
bool Order::add(int n)
```

I need to check if n is greater than 0 and the object is not empty.(data members are 0 or null) I'm not really sure how to go around doing this to check if the object is not empty since I can't use *this in a conditional. Any help would be appreciated.

Here is the class:

```
#include "ean.h"

class Order {
    int copies;
    int delivered;
    bool filled = false;
    EAN eanno;
public:
    Order();
    Order(const EAN& ean);
    EAN& getEAN();
    int outstanding() const;
    bool add(std::istream& is);
    bool add(int n);
    bool receive(std::istream& is);
    void display(std::ostream& os) const;
};
std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& os, const Order& order);
```

Here are the two constructors:

```
Order::Order() {
    copies = 0;
    delivered = 0;
    this->eanno;
}

Order::Order(const EAN& ean) {
    Order();
    this->eanno = ean;
}
```

Comment: Define "empty", please. And who said you can't use `*this`? If it's inside a member function, you can.

Comment: You can add one extra member in your class 'Order' like size which should contain the size. SO while adding you can check it whether empty or not by checking size == 0 or not. Same concept has been used in C++ STL container design.

Comment: empty as in the data members are 0 or null. I thought you couldn't inside a conditional unless you overloaded the == operator, which I can't do for this particular object.

Comment: Added the class and the constructor definitions

Comment: do you really want to have a constructor that allows an empty EAN object to be created? You are making unnecessary copies of EAN here. If an object of type Order should exist without an EAN you may want to use a pointer instead of a reference here, so you can initialize it as nullptr while it doesn't have one. The easiest choice here (to keep using EAN&) would be to get rid of the default constructor.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you are asking about testing for `if (*this == 0)` which is not what you want because `*this` has always been initialized by the constructor and will never return 0 or nullptr. You want to test it's members instead.

You should define empty() for your class (if it doesn't already exists) for clarity :

```
bool Order::empty() const {
  return m1 == 0 && m2 == nullptr;  // whatever conditions you use to define whether your object is null goes here. Don't test on *this because it will always be a constructed object, never null.
}

bool Order::add(const int n) {
   if (n > 0 && empty()) { 
     ... // your code goes here
     return true;
   }
   return false;
}
```

consider making it const if you're not changing anything inside the structure.

Answer (score 1):

Without any information on the class, it is difficult to answer. How about this ? :

```
bool Order::add(int n)
{
   if( n > 0 )
      if( member1 != 0 || member2 != 0 || member3 != 0 )
      {
         ... // do something
      }
}
```

Or maybe I didn't understand the question ?